# Polling multiple servers

Tags: python, multithreading

I have an application which polls a bunch of servers every few minutes. To do this, it spawns one thread per server to poll (15 servers) and writes back the data to an object:

```
import requests
import threading
import time


servers = ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2']


class CallThreads(threading.Thread):
    """
    Auxiliary class used to provide arguments to threads
    """

    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run (self):
        self.target(*self.args)


class ServerResults(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.results_list = []

    def add_server(some_argument):
        self.results_list.append(some_argument)


def poll_server(server, results):
    response = requests.get(server, timeout=10)
    results.add_server(response.status_code);


def process_results(results):
    # Do something with the results


def main():
    while True:
        results = ServerResults()
        for s in servers:
            t = CallThreads(poll_server, s, results)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        time.sleep(300)
        process_results(results.results_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my first non-trivial Python application, so I would appreciate any critique, comments, or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Is the while statement supposed to be in the `process_results` function?

Comment: Thank you Aseem. No, the `while` statement is not in the `process_results()` function. I have added a `main()` function to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The two classes seem useless to me.</strike>

`ServerResults` only contains a list, so just use a list. *Edit: see comment below.*

The `CallThreads` class is unnecessary, this:

```
t = CallThreads(poll_server, s, results)
```

can be written like that:

```
t = Thread(target=poll_server, args=(s, results))
```

Note that you could also use the [`partial` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
t = Thread(target=partial(poll_server, s, results))
```

or a `lambda`:

```
t = Thread(target=lambda: poll_server(s, results))
```

Comment: Thank you. `ServerResults` is actually much more than a list, I just show a list in this example code for simplicity's sake. I am interested in this `partial` function, where is this documented? Googling for `python target=partial` turns up some blog posts but no real documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I was going to put a link to the documentation but forgot. It's in the standard library: [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). `target` is a keyword argument of `Thread()`, you simply had to search for `python partial`.

Comment: Great, thanks. I had to add `from functools import partial`. I'm still playing with it, thank you.

Comment: The code which uses target=partial [is segfaulting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577851/intermittent-segmentation-fault-have-coredump?noredirect=1#comment27336518_18577851), please see the [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577851/intermittent-segmentation-fault-have-coredump?noredirect=1#comment27336518_18577851).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about debugging segfaults. Have you tried [using gdb](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) ?

Comment: Thanks. I think it is something else that is causing the segfaulting, possibly in the `requests` library.